# Is it better to use the standard xgboost package or the one from github?

Tags: r, xgboost

The one from github is updated per week? Does that mean it is not stable? But how about functionality? Should we still use the github one because they support more powerful functions?

Comment: Occasionally the development (GitHub) version of a package gets significantly ahead of its official (CRAN) release, but most of the time they're not that different; most changes in mature packages are minor bug fixes. Particularly with a package that requires compiling, CRAN can be a lot simpler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think its better to use the standard xgboost package.